# Multiple linear system, same solution

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I know how to solve the problem

`Ax=B`

with matlab, I just use `mldivide` to obtain x: `x=A\B`

But what if I have multiple basis `A_i` and multiple data `B_i` but the nature of the problem suggests me that the solution `x` must be the same for every `i`?

Comment: Then it's enough to solve only one of the problems ;-)

Comment: When I said "the same" I ment "similar". I have multiple data and I want to "regularize" the solution across all data.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "regularize". [And beware that "the same" is not the same as "similar". :-)]

Comment: The nature of the problem suggests they would be the same, but since I deal with experimental data they won't. So a first approximation could be the least square solution.

Comment: You still don't provide enough information. What do you mean by "regularize" ? If you simply have an overdetermined system, use the least-squares solution, unless there are outliers. Please describe your problem.

Comment: Ok, no, I've not been precise. Forget "regularize". I have to estimate some parameters `x` but I can't do it directly. So, what I can do is make some measurement `B_i` collected respect to certain basis `A_i` (they are not "mathematical basis of the space", allow it to me). The vector `A_i` is given and synthetic while `B_i` is measured, so it is subject to experimental error.

Comment: What do you call a "basis" ? I guess that explicitly stating the equations would enlighten us.

Comment: Forget "basis", it was an attempt to explain myself. There is no equations. Consider a single `A_i` as a collect of n vectorized images registered by the i-th set of cameras. I have multiple set of cameras. `B_i` is the resulting image obtained by a linear combination of the images weighed with the coefficients `x`.

Comment: More and more obscure. If your images are "vectorized" (how?), then you can't combine them with a linear combination. I thought that your Xi were the unknowns, so you need some criterion to obtain their values.

Comment: Ok. Let forget the `i` index as well. I try to explain it in the simpler case. Consider you have some simple images, `U_1`, `U_2`, `U_3`, and a linear combination of them, `V`. We can write `x_1 * U_1 + x_2 * U_2 + x_3 * U_3 = V`. Our data are `U_1`, `U_2`, `U_3` and `V`. I want to find the vector `x = [x_1, x_2, x_3]`. How can I do that?

Comment: My implicit answere is: I vectorize every images, matlab speaking: `U = U(:)` (vertical vector), and I build the matrix `A = [U_1, U_2, U_3]' and 'B = V(:)', so the problem becames `Ax=B`. Am I right up to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try stacking the A matrices and B vectors to obtain a larger least squares system. That is, form

```
A = (A_1)
    ...
    (A_n)
```

and

```
B = (B_1)
    ...
    (B_n)
```

and then solve

```
A*x = B
```

in the least squares sense

The solution x to such a system will be the value that minimises

```
Sum{ || A_i*x - B_i ||^2 }
```

Comment: Thank you. In the meanwhile I get this solution too. I do not think it has any contraindications.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is an image "unmixing" problem, which requests the solution of a (highly) overdetermined system of W x H equations (image area) in K unknowns (number of end members).

One wants to solve

```
X1.U1ij + X2.U2ij + X3.U3ij = Vij
```

(assuming `K=3`) where `i`, `j` cover the whole image.

The standard solutions will be least-squares minimization, with two caveats:

- if there are outliers the results canbe badly biased and robust methods should be preferred;
- if this is really a mixture problem, then the coefficients are constrained to be positive and the question should be recast as a linear programming problem.

Comment: Can you suggest me an outliers-robust method?

Comment: RANSAC is one of them. In you r case, it would mean take three random pixels, solve the system, detect and count outliers and repeat for other triples, keeping the best solution. In the end, perform ordinary fitting on the inliers.

Comment: I've found this function `lsqnonneg` for the second case you mentioned http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lsqnonneg.html;jsessionid=fa9122eb60c8423b00a5b912ef1c . But I don't get how can I use RANSAC for solving an overdetermited linear system?

Comment: @Giorgio: just like I said in the previous comment.

Comment: I don't know how to "detect and count outliers".